# Strange jpanel paint

Tags: java, jpanel, paint

here is my class

```
public class Grid extends JPanel{
    public Grid(Dimension dim){
        this.dim = dim;
        step = 0.02;
        this.setSize(dim);
        this.setLocation(0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        for(int i=-1; i<this.getHeight(); i+=this.getHeight()*step){
            g.drawLine(0, i, this.getWidth(), i);
        }
        for(int i=-1; i<this.getWidth(); i+=this.getWidth()*step){
            g.drawLine(i, 0, i, this.getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

(I skipped the definition of class variables)

I add this class in another JPanel like this

```
Grid grid = new Grid(dim);
parentPanel.add(grid);
```

By default, the grid is hidden ( `grid.hide();` ) so my jFrame looks something like this:
[image]

where the "blue" area is the parentPanel and the "orange" area is a JPanel with buttons. The problem is that when I press the grid button, I get the following result:[image]

where the grid lines are ok, but I get also this orange box which I do not know why is there.

Any ideas?

Comment: what are these buttons at the top? are you sure you didn't add a button also to the panel? I think you posted too few code to be able to help.

Comment: they are random buttons of my program, yes I did not add any button to the panel (forgot to mention that I can add other JPanels as well that can be moved with the mouse over the panel. if I move one of these over the strange orange box, it disappears like it is being erased)

Comment: maybe it is required to call `super.paint()` in `public void paint(Graphics g);`?

Comment: when I used `super.paint()` it paints the background white, not transparent and if I use `this.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));` the same strange box appears

Comment: are you sure that the second button is always there but is visible only if you use a transparent background? also I think it is better than you call super.paint() from a design perspective.

Comment: I am not sure that it is there under the white background, but since I need the transparent background for this project I have no idea how to remove this box

Comment: have you tried to remove all the buttons?

Comment: if I remove all the buttons I will not be able to trigger on the grid, since by default is hidden. if the grid is set on by default the box is not there. but if I trigger off and on again, the box is there

Comment: when you click the button you recreate the button object?

Comment: no, the button is created just once, when I click it, it just run `grid.show();`

Comment: it copies somehow the content of another jpanel..

Comment: You should be overriding `paintComponent()` of `JPanel`, not `paint()`, no?

Comment: does the same thing for what I need. (also had the same problem)

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following line inside my constructor

```
this.setOpaque(false);
```